# HTTPS request from Axios.js to a Flask Python HTTPS server using TLS and PEM certificates

Tags: ssl, flask, https, axios, pem

I am not able to perform an HTTPS request from Axios.js to a Flask HTTPS server.

I think the reason might be related to the way the Axios.js object is configured, because I see that the requests are using HTTPS + a PEM certificate, but I don't see any reason why the Axios.js instance is misconfigured (see https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

The error I see when running the Javascript code is `Error: self signed certificate`, which looks weird to me because I think the HTTPS client should use a `PEM` certificate as self-signed (e.g. like a web browser).
Checking the HTTPS agent here https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback and here https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback it seems I should set `rejectUnauthorized` to `false`. If I do that and then remove those fields `cert` and `key`, then the code works, but that would mean not using TLS at all, so I am not sure what's the point of TLS.

The Javascript HTTP(S) client using Axios.js:

```js
const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  cert: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../../../ssl_cert.crt`),
  key: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../../../ssl_cert.key`),
})

const myApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:5000', // the Flask server
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  httpsAgent: agent,
});
```

The certificates have been created with these commands:

```sh
# generate the 2 files: crt and key
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes \
        -keyout ssl_cert.key -x509 -days 365 -out ssl_cert.crt \
        -subj "/C=GB/ST=England/L=London/O=foo/CN=foo"
# inspect the crt file (e.g. check the expiry date)
openssl x509 -text -noout -in ssl_cert.crt
```

Both the `crt` and the `key` start with `-----BEGIN` so I think they should already be in the `PEM` format. AFAIK I could use the `crt` file as the `PEM` certificate when performing the HTTPS requests from the Axios.js client.

This is the Python Flask server as the backend responding to the Javascript frontend:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
ssl_context = (
        "{...}/../ssl_cert.crt",
        "{...}/../ssl_cert.key",
    )

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

- What's wrong with these certificates?
- How can I make secure connections (HTTP + S) between a Javascript client and a Python server?